# To build patch clusters with a symmetrical shape given a specified area

Tags: netlogo

To build patch clusters with a given symmetrical shape from their area, I used the following code :

```
to make-cluster
let Forest-size 60000
let patch-area 10
let forest-patch-number Forest-size / patch-area
let patch-number 1
let increment-patch 1
let random-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
let cluster[] 

while [patch-number <= forest-patch-number] [

ask random-patch [set cluster patches in-radius increment-patch]

ifelse all? cluster [pcolor = black] [ 
ask cluster [set pcolor green] 
set patch-number count patches with [pcolor = green] 
set increment-patch increment-patch + 1 ] 

[set random-patch one-of patches with [pcolor = black]
set increment-patch 1] ]
end 

to create-forests
let forest-percent 0
let Forest-% 10
while [ forest-percent < Forest-% ] [ 
make-cluster 
set forest-percent round ( (count patches with [pcolor = green] / count patches) * 100 ) ] 
end
```

When I run the code, "increment-patch" is always equal to 2. In fact, I don't understand why the "else" of "ifelse" loop is always done at each time step.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The first time through the `ifelse`, all the patches in the cluster might be black, and if they are, you'll take the “then” branch. In the “then” branch, you turn the patches in the cluster green. The next time through `ifelse`, the condition (all patches in cluster being black) can never be true, because you *only just turned those very same patches green!* So the second time through you always take the “else” branch, so `increment-patch` never exceeds 2.

Not sure I understand the intent behind the code. You want the cluster to keep growing, I guess? When do you want it stop growing?